# Group By with Where

Tags: sql, t-sql

I want to do a group by on a dataset with a where clause based upon a `datetime`, but I need to return a count of 0 for any users in the `Account` table that do not meet the `where date` requirement.  Here is my SQL statement:

```
select a.userid, count(c.codeentryid)
from [account] a
left join codesentered c
on a.userid = c.userid
where a.camp = 0 and c.entrydate > '2013-12-03 00:00:00'
group by a.userid
order by a.userid
```

Currently I get counts for all the users who meet the `entrydate` requirement, but how would I also return the users who don't meet this requirement with a count of 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are using a `left join`, all conditions on the *second* table should go into the `on` clause.  Otherwise, the outer join becomes an inner join.  So, try this:

```
select a.userid, count(c.codeentryid)
from [account] a left join
     codesentered c
     on a.userid = c.userid and c.entrydate > '2013-12-03 00:00:00'
where a.camp = 0 
group by a.userid
order by a.userid;
```

Conditions on the first table, in the `on` clause are basically ignored.  A `left join` returns all rows from the first table, even when the `on` clause evaluates to false or `NULL`.

Answer (score 2):

You can include the condition in the `join`. Since it is a `left outer join`, it will always show all records from `account`, and only those of `codesentered` which match the condition:

```
select a.userid, count(c.codeentryid)
from [account] a
left outer join codesentered c
on   a.userid = c.userid
/* here */ and  c.entrydate > '2013-12-03 00:00:00'
where a.camp = 0 
group by a.userid
order by a.userid
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this maybe.  It would be easier to test with some sample data.

```
select a.userid, SUM(CASE WHEN c.entrydate > '2013-12-03 00:00:00' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
from [account] a
left join codesentered c
on a.userid = c.userid
where a.camp = 0 
group by a.userid
order by a.userid
```